# Cannot downcast on an object which has been loaded from a .so library

Tags: c++, casting, shared-libraries, abstract, dynamic-linking

I'm currently working on a game engine which implements an architecture based on frameworks.

These frameworks are dynamically loaded into the engine through the using of .so libraries.

To illustrate the frameworks usage, here is a little picture:
[Engine/Frameworks interactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNdgo.png)

*(please, note that the engine also knows about the FrameworkTpl and SpecificFrameworkTpl types)*

As we can see, the *specificFrameworkImplementation* class is compiled as a shared library (.so) and inherit from *specificFrameworkTpl* which itself inherit from *FrameworkTpl*.

Once compiled, the library is loaded into the engine at runtime and an instance of the framework is retrieved as a *FrameworkTpl*.

At this time if I call a *FrameworkTpl* method, it will works like a charm (which is pretty obvious yes...).

Neverless, if I try to down cast this instance to a *specificFrameworkTpl* with the help of a `dynamic_cast`, it will return a `nullptr`.

Through my research (which have last for about one week while reading mans pages and StackOverflow answers), I saw peoples talking about flags to give to the `dlopen` function such as **RTLD_NOW** or to remove like **RTLD_LOCAL** in favor of **RTLD_GLOBAL**, but none of them has worked for me, same thing for g++ flags (`-rdynamic`).

**The code:**

Here is an example with `GuiFrameworkTpl` as `specificFrameworkTpl`
and `FrameworkUI` for `specificFrameworkImplementation`.

*FrameworkTpl*

```
class FrameworkTpl
{
protected:
    std::string _name;

public:
    FrameworkTpl(const std::string &name):
        _name(name)
    {
    }

    virtual ~FrameworkTpl(void)
    {
    }

public:
    virtual std::string getName(void) const
    {
        return (this->_name);
    }
};
```

*GuiFrameworkTpl*

```
class GuiFrameworkTpl : public FrameworkTpl
{
public:
    GuiFrameworkTpl(const std::string & name) : 
        FrameworkTpl(name)
    {
    }
    virtual ~GuiFrameworkTpl(void)
    {
    }

    virtual void displaySquare(int x, int y, int size) = 0;
};
```

*FrameworkUI*

```
class FrameworkUI : public GuiFrameworkTpl
{
public:
    FrameworkUI();
    ~FrameworkUI();

public:
    void displaySquare(int x, int y, int size);
};

extern "C"
{
    FrameworkUI* CObject()
    {
        return (new FrameworkUI);
    }

    void DObject(FrameworkUI* obj)
    {
        delete obj;
    }
}
```

App that uses the library and cast stuff from it:
*(Here, the Xxx from the previous classes is used as "Gui")*

```
GuiFrameworkTpl* GUISystem::cast_f(const std::shared_ptr<FrameworkTpl>& src)
{
    auto ptr = src.get();
    Log::print(ptr);
    if (!ptr) return nullptr;
    Log::inform(ptr->getName());
    auto dst = dynamic_cast<GuiFrameworkTpl*>(ptr);
    Log::print(dst);
    return dst;
}
```

**What I should have:**

When I load my library and call `CObject()` it should create an instance of *FrameworkUI* which I get in a *FrameworkTpl*, then I would just have to dynamic_cast it as a *GuiFrameworkTpl* in order to access particular method.

**What I really have:**

When I load my library and call `CObject()` it creates an instance of *FrameworkUI* which I store in a *FrameworkTpl* (btw, I can call the `getName()` method successfully, so the instance is valid). But when I try to down cast it to *GuiFrameworkTpl*, it gives me a `nullptr`.

The last function print this:

```
0xc0c200
[INFO]: FrameworkUI
0
```

If anyone has some clue about how to solve this problem, I would be very grateful,
Thanks in advance

Comment: `XxxFrameworkImplementation` - what's this unrelated class that you're trying to cast it to?

Comment: `interpreted as a FrameworkTpl` no, you're just returning a pointer to a FrameworkXxx.  if you decide to downcast it to a FrameworkTpl when you call assign the result after calling CObject, that's not posted

Comment: @UKMonkey I've edited the question to add the code I use to cast from FrameworkTpl to specific Framework (here Gui)

Comment: @UKMonkey It was a typo, it should be XxxFrameworkTpl instead of XxxFrameworkImplementation. Fixed, sorry.

Comment: ok, so what's this `GuiFrameworkTpl` that you're trying to cast it to?  dynamic_cast returns null if the types are unrelated.  You're trying to cast objects into other objects that they're not.

Comment: In the question, Xxx is there to indicate that it can be replaced by any keyword. GuiFrameworkTpl is just a XxxFrameworkTpl where I replaced all the "Xxx" by "Gui". I was trying to be generic, but it may have failed.Sorry if it was unclear, it's my first question on stack overflow. Moreover, the classes are normally perfectly related (GuiFrameworkTpl inherit from FrameworkTpl)

Comment: Please update the question with a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: By curiosity test this command to see if the type info and the vtable of GuiFrameworkTpl is in a relocation section: `readelf -r <PATH_TO_LIB.so> | c++filt`, look for line ending by "typeinfo for GuiFrameworkTpl" and "vtable for GuiFrameworkTpl". If it is not exported, it means it will be impossible to do the downcast (or if you realy need it, there is a hack)

Comment: I've updated it and tried to make it the clearest possible. If anything remains not correct, I still can edit it.

Comment: @Oliv thanks a lot for the answer, after verification, there is no trace of typeinfo or vtable for "GuiFrameworkTpl". Nevertheless, the only mentions to GuiFrameworkTpl are 3 lines such as : `000000203060  003100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000001c08 _ZN2nx15GuiFrameworkTp + 0`

Comment: So it means that GuiFrameworkTp, as a private vtable inside the library. And inside your executable, the compiler also create a vtable for GuiFrameworkTp. When you do a dynamic_cast, the code checks if the pointer to the vtable is the one expected, and this naturaly fails. So you should just don't use GuiFrameworkTp. Essentialy, it is a flaw in the design of the library, either the symbol should have been visible in the .so otherwise the header where GuiFrameworkTp should be private.

Comment: The hack, that I advice you not to do!! would consist in updating the vtable pointer in the object. Normaly, if you use a recent compiler, this pointer is at the same address as the object (first member). Try it for fun.

Comment: If you can recompile the library, it's easy, change the visibility attribute for the class GuiFrameworkTp.

Comment: You could also reinterpret_cast, but you are probably also going to have a lot of horrible problems if you do that.

Comment: Well, I tried the reinterpret_cast earlier and it resulted in a segmentation fault. Next, since all the visibilities are set to public, what do you mean by "change the visibility attribute for the class GuiFrameworkTpl"? And finally, by saying "would consist in updating the vtable pointer in the object." I don't exactly see what you mean. Sorry if I don't fully understand what you said, but I'm not totally comfortable with vtables.